# Add dict file in json with python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

i hv same code like this

```
import json

param1 = "xxxxxx"
param2 = "anaaaahhhhhhhhhj"
param3 = "333333333"

with open('data/'+param1+'.json','a') as f:
    data = param2,
    json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=1,ensure_ascii=False)
```

when i executed this, the output like this, not real dictionary

```
[
 "anaaaahhhhhhhhhj"
][
 "anaaaahhhhhhhhhj"
]
```

i want

```
[
 "anaaaahhhhhhhhhj"
][
 "anaaaahhhhhhhhhj"
]
```

to

```
[
 "anaaaahhhhhhhhhj",
 "blablablabal"
]
```

anyone can help me?

ps: i new in python

Comment: Your question is confusing. You are talking about dictionaries, for there is none. Also your result can only be like that if you run the script twice which you also ommited. Please edit your question and add a proper description of your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing with a list and trying to append to it each time you run the script: Load the list first, perform an append operation, and dump it back out.

This assumes you have an existing file named "mydata.json" with `[]` in it.

First method (more understandable):

```
import json

fileName = 'mydata.json'

# Load the list first
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Perform an append operation
data.append('New Value')

# Dump it back out
with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Second method (using seek):

```
import json

fileName = 'mydata.json'

with open(fileName, 'r+') as f:
    # Load the list first
    data = json.load(f)

    # Perform an append operation
    data.append('New Value')

    # Dump it back out
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False)
    f.truncate()
```

Running either of these programs 3 times will result in "mydata.json" containing:

```
[
 "New Value",
 "New Value",
 "New Value"
]
```